# Testing a component that disappears after a short time

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There is a global Snackbar component that I am writing tests for. The component itself is quite simple.

It has some text showing the status (which is **not** a prop **nor** a data property, but rather derived from the object sent with the `EventBus.$emit` call).

After three seconds, the component disappears OR renders another snackbar stored in an array within the component itself.

So I want to test for two things here:

1. Only one snackbar appears (which I believe I have gotten) at any given time.
2. After three seconds the other snackbar should appear.

Here is my code so far:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/vue'
import Snackbar from '../Snackbar.vue'
import EventBus from '@/services/EventBus'

describe('Snackbar', () => {
  const role = 'alert'

  it('should show only one snackbar at a time and should disappear after 3 seconds', async () => {
    const { getByRole } = render(Snackbar, {stubs: ['ButtonComponent']})
    for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
      const text = `Hello ${x}`    
      await EventBus.$emit('addSnack', { text })
    }

    const snackbar = getByRole(role)
    expect(snackbar).toHaveTextContent('Hello 0')

    // This might be redundant?
    expect(snackbar).not.toHaveTextContent('Hello 1')
    
    // Here is the problem (this never throws an error)
    await waitFor(() => {
      const snackbar2 = getByRole(role)
      expect(snackbar2).toHaveTextContent('Hello 1');
    }, 3500)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `it` test asynchronous:

```js
it('should detect an asynchronous thing', async () => {

  await waitFor(() => {
    const something = myFunction();
    expect(something).toBe(true);
  }, 3500);

});
```

See [JEST > Testing Asynchronous Code > Async/Await](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#asyncawait)

Comment: That was actually a typo on my part, I have async already.